# How to sort by dynamic column in Fluent Vapor 3

Tags: mysql, fluent, vapor-fluent

How do I execute SQL query like this in Fluent?

```
SELECT `book`.*
  FROM `book`
  JOIN `book_user` ON `book`.`id` = `book_user`.`bookId`
GROUP BY `book`.`id`
ORDER BY COUNT(`book`.`id`) DESC;
```

I tried to achieve this using:

```
Book.query(on: req)
    .join(UserBookPivot.self, field: \UserBookPivot.bookId, to: \Book.id, method: .inner)
    .group(by: \Book.id)
    .sort(\Book.id, .descending)
    .all()
```

which only produced a query like this:

```
SELECT * 
--     ^
  FROM `book` 
  JOIN `book_user` ON `book`.`id` = `book_user`.`bookId` 
GROUP BY `book`.`id` 
ORDER BY `book`.`id` DESC;
--       ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Still can't find a way to produce `ORDER BY COUNT(book.id)` and `SELECT book.*`.

Is it possible to do this in the current version of vapor besides using `.simpleQuery(_:)` manually?

Env:

> Vapor: 3.0.0.rc-2.7
>
> Fluent: 3.0.0.rc-2.3.3
>
> Fluent-mysql: 3.0.0.rc-2.3

Comment: I don’t think ordering by a computed column is available through fluent atm. That would be a good feature request. However you should be able to use the `customSQL` method on query builder to do that without having to write the whole query in sql. There are no docs on that stuff yet (will come with the official release) but you should be able to figure it out by poking around. :)

Comment: Ah, I didn't pay too much attention on `customSQL` before. I'll see what I can do with it. Thanks for pointing it out.